# Haskell Passing from do notation to Applicative

Tags: haskell

I am trying to strip away do notation in the Database.sh file from https://haskell-at-work.com/episodes/2018-01-19-domain-modelling-with-haskell-data-structures.html

But I am having an Error and I have no Idea why. (Probably just means I don't know about Haskell)

#### Haskell Code:

###### Project.hs

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Project where

import           Data.Text (Text)

newtype Money = Money
  { unMoney :: Double
  } deriving (Show, Eq, Num)

newtype ProjectId = ProjectId
  { unProjectId :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Eq, Num)

data Project
  = Project ProjectId
            Text
  | ProjectGroup Text
                 [Project]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Budget = Budget
  { budgetIncome      :: Money
  , budgetExpenditure :: Money
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Transaction
  = Sale Money
  | Purchase Money
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

###### Database

```hs
import           System.Random (getStdRandom, randomR)

import Project

getBudget :: ProjectId -> IO Budget
getBudget _ = Budget
    <$> (Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 10000)))
    <*> (Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 10000)))

getTransactions :: ProjectId -> IO [Transaction]
getTransactions _ = let rtn = []
    <$>  (Sale . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
    <*> (Purchase . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
  in
    pure rtn
```

#### Error

After running `stack ghc Database.hs --package random`

```
[2 of 2] Compiling Database         ( Database.hs, Database.o )

Database.hs:12:5: error: parse error on input `<$>'
   |
12 |     <$>  (Sale . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
   |     ^^^
```

Comment: `[] <$> x <*> y` isn't going to be valid, regardless of the indentation. Consider using `sequence [x, y]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple indentation error.

Remember that the syntax of `let <definitions> in <expr>` allows there to be a block of *multiple* definitions. "A block of multiple things"<sup>1</sup> is basically always the context where indentation matters in Haskell, and the rule is always that each of the "things" in the block must start at the same column *and if they span more than one line the continuation lines must all be more indented than the alignment column for the block*.

That means that this is good:

```
something = let foo = 1
                bar = 2
                baz = 3
             in foo + bar + baz
```

Because the `f`, `b`, and `b` starting each of the equations in the `let` block line up at the same column. This is also good:

```
something = let
  foo = 1
  bar = 2
  baz = 3
        in foo + bar + baz
```

Because the equations still line up exactly. It does not matter that the position they line up at is actually *less* indented than the `let` keyword itself, nor does it matter that the `in` keyword is even further indented.

But this is bad:

```
getTransactions :: ProjectId -> IO [Transaction]
getTransactions _ = let rtn = []
    <$>  (Sale . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
    <*> (Purchase . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
  in
    pure rtn
```

Because the block of definitions inside the `let` *starts* with `rtn = []`. Everything that's part of that first definition has to be indented further than the `r` from `rtn`. To correct it you either need something like:

```
getTransactions :: ProjectId -> IO [Transaction]
getTransactions _ = let rtn = []
                         <$>  (Sale . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
                         <*> (Purchase . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
  in
    pure rtn
```

Where you indent the following lines more. Or (to avoid excessive indentation) do something like this:

```
getTransactions :: ProjectId -> IO [Transaction]
getTransactions _ =
  let rtn = []
        <$>  (Sale . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
        <*> (Purchase . Money <$> getStdRandom (randomR (0, 4000)))
  in
    pure rtn
```

There are various ways you can do this; you could put the `=` from `getTransactions` on the next line too, or you could leave the `let` on the previous line and only move the `rtn = []` down, etc. But once you start the block of definitions, you have to continue the rule that everything that's part of an entry in the block must be further indented; you can't reset back out mid-block.

---

<sup>1</sup> `do` blocks have multiple statements, `let` and `where` blocks have multiple definitions, `case` blocks have multiple branches, modules have multiple imports and definitions (conventionally we align these at indentation level 0, but you don't have to), etc, etc.

The indentation of anything else does *not* matter, and is purely a matter of convention and readibility (`if/then/else`, the `in` part of a `let/in`, guards or other parts of a function definition, etc)